# Trying to select appropriate distribution for GLMM in r

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I have a relatively small dataset (160 observations), of which a very large number of my response variables are zero or very small (e.g., 131/160 values are 0; range 0-1.56).  I had originally planned to use GLMM and select an appropriate distribution, but have not been able to find one that is a good fit.  I've tried gamma, log-normal, Weibull, and beta.

I would like to try (and had recommended to me) Poisson and negative binomial, and also zero-inflated Poisson, but when I try to see how these fit using `fitdist` (in `fitdistr`) I get the following error message:

```
fitpois <- fitdist(variable_scaled, "pois")
```

> simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs
>   = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): initial value
>   in 'vmmin' is not finite> Error in fitdist(variable_scaled, "pois") : 
>   the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
>                   with the error code 100

I have tried scaling the data to avoid having values of exactly zero in the data using:

```
variable_scaled <- (variable-min(variable)+0.001)/(max(variable)-min(variable)+0.002)
```

Any suggestions for what is causing the error code?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Poisson and negative binomial are for integer valued responses.  If your range is 0-1.56 that would imply some sort of continuous measure.

Comment: You seem to be looking for zero inflated models. See [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279273/zero-inflated-distributions-what-are-they-really), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) and [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zip/). A CRAN package for these models is package [pscl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/index.html).